# Only displaying database rows that match the ID of the user that created it

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a HTML table that's displaying all of my database's data (individual job listings). However, I need to write an if statement to only show a job if the job's createdByUserID matches the ID of the user viewing it.

```
$(function() {
    var records = [];
    $.getJSON('https://db-ommitted-for-privacy?tableName=JobListings&fields=company,logo,img,companyDescription,role,roleDescription,location,link,createdByUserID,dateAdded&view=AllListings', function(data) {
        $.each(data.records, function parseJSON(i, { fields: f }) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + 
                "<td>" + 
                    "<div style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;'>" + 
                        "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + 
                            "<button class='accordionList' style='font-size: large; outline: none;'>" + 
                                "<span style='padding-top: 2.5%; padding-bottom: 3%;'>" + 
                                    "<img src='" + f.logo + "' height='30px'>" + 
                                "</span> &nbsp;<span style='padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3%;'>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + 
                                    f.company + " &nbsp; | &nbsp; " + f.role + 
                                " &nbsp;&nbsp; <span style='color: #2b2b2b;''><span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='eva:pin-outline' style='color: #2b2b2b;'></span> " + f.location +"</span></span>" + 
                            "</button>" + 
                            "<div class='panel'>" + 
                                "<img src='img/jobBanner2.png' width='100%'>" +
                                "<br>" + 
                                "<p style='color: #505050;'>Posted: " + f.dateCreated + " &nbsp; | &nbsp; Status: " + f.status + "</p>" + 
                                "<h4>About this role:</h4>" + 
                                "<p>" + f.roleDescription + "</p>" + 
                                "<h4>About " + f.company + ":</h4>" + 
                                "<p>" + f.companyDescription + "</p>" + "<br>" + 
                                "<a href='pricing.html' class='button btn btn-lg btn-block btn-sm button-black' style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; width: 200px;'>Apply &nbsp; <span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='bi:arrow-right-circle' data-width='15' style='color: white;'></span></a>" + 
                                "<br>" + "</div>" + 
                            "</div>" + 
                        "</div>" + 
                    "</div>" + 
                "</td>" + 
            "</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
    });
});
```

The code to display a logged in user's ID:

```
<div data-ms-member="id"></div>
```

I understand the concept of how this should work, but I have no idea how to execute it in JS and HTML. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add:

```js
var uid = /*get your user id here*/
//filter out any data not created by current user
if (uid != f.createdByUserID) {return ;}
```

before this line

```js
var tblRow = "<tr>" +
```

What I still have to say is that, it is silly to do the filtering at front-end, for causing both security risk of exposing your database to everybody using developer tools to check your code, and low performance as a result of trying to recieve all the data in a database table from the server. It would be better to have a back-end written in php or node.js doing these checkings.

Comment: Don't call people *stupid*, I'm sure you still make silly mistakes....

Comment: @RenevanderLende Sorry, it might sound rude, but I am not trying to say _anyone_ is stupid here. I'm Just saying that the code looks stupid. I call my own code stupid my self many times a day, actually. Not trying to be offensive :)

Comment: @RenevanderLende I edited my answer to replace 'stupid' with 'silly', which makes it sound better